# How to focus on `ag-Grid` so the next key press is a key event from `ag-Grid` itself

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I made a custom navigation component for `ag-Grid`.

Once action from the user happens, I want to focus on one of `ag-Grid`'s rows or cells, as if the user simply clicked one of `ag-Grid`'s cells themselves.

So after this focusing, the next time I press a key like `Up`/`Down`/`Left`/`Right`, it is registered as an `ag-Grid`'s keyboard interaction event ([Keyboard Interaction: Core Feature of our Datagrid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-keyboard-navigation/#navigatetonextcell)).

To be more concrete, the `navigateToNextCell()` hook should get called once an arrow key is pressed.

How do I do this?

I tried:

- `gridApi.setFocusedCell(0, 0)`
- `gridApi.dispatchEvent({ type: 'cellFocused', rowIndex, column })`
- `document.querySelector('.ag-root-wrapper').focus()`

None of these worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focusing on a row node works, given the row index `index`:

```js
const rowNode = document.querySelector(`.ag-row[row-index="${index}"] > .ag-cell`)
if (rowNode) {
  rowNode.focus()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const col = 'your column field name';
gridApi.ensureColumnVisible(col);
gridApi.setFocusedCell(0, col);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**